# laravel - should I use sub-query to get info inside Grouped data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This query is running fine:

```
<?php
$q = DB::table('stock_parts')
      ->addSelect('stock_parts.id')
      ->addSelect('stock_parts.title')
      ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(stock_items.id) AS available'))
      ->selectRaw('SUM(shipments.item_cost) AS totalValue')
      ->leftJoin('stock_items', function($join) use ($stockId) {
        $join->on('stock_items.stock_part_id', '=', 'stock_parts.id');
        $join->where('stock_items.current_stock_id', $stockId);
      })
      ->leftJoin('shipments', function($join){
        $join->on('shipments.id', '=', 'stock_items.shipment_id');
      })
      ->groupBy('stock_parts.id', 'stock_parts.title')
      ->orderBy('stock_parts.title', 'ASC')
      ->get()->toArray();
```

It brings total numbers like these:

```
0 => {
  +"id"         : 171
  +"title"      : "PART NAME"
  +"totalValue" : 9.0
  +"available"  : 7
}
```

Now I'm trying to get also items information separated by Supplier:

```
0 => {
  +"id"...
  +"available_by_seller":[
    {"supplier_id":1, "available":xxx, "totalValue":xxx},
    {"supplier_id":2, "available":xxx, "totalValue":xxx},
    {"supplier_id":3, "available":xxx, "totalValue":xxx}
  ]
}
```

My model structure is:

```
StockPart // each part meta data
  - title
  - hasMany StockItem
  - hasMany Shipments

Shipment
  - qty
  - item_cost
  - belongsTo Supplier
  - belongsTo StockPart
  - hasMany StockItems

StockItem // each part item
  - belongsTo StockPart
  - belongsTo Shipment

Supplier
  - hasMany Shipment
```

I've got no clue on how to achieve this.

Should I rewrite entire query starting from another table?

Or maybe just add a sub select or group by?

Comment: Why don't you use Eloquent query?

Comment: @DilipHirapara I have more than 1200 items in database, so It's not a good idea to loop and query each one.